# Can't choose variations for WooCommerce product created programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-attributes

I am using a custom PHP Script to create variations of a WooCommerce product. The user chooses "Size" and "Color" of the product through a select field, and the variations is created based on that.

Works fine, product is created with the correct price, attribute and variations. **Except that you cant select the actual variations when trying to shop (they are "disabled").**

When I go back-end in WooCommerce and open the product there, and hit the blue "Update"-button on the product, it works as intended and the variations can be selected and bought front-end.

Is there any function to "force update" the product in PHP after variations have been created?

[image: After creating the product/variations programatically]

--

[image: After hitting Update-button back-end it works as intended]

*Below the code which adds color and size as attributes to the product. Also creates a single variation with "Any color" and "Any size" as the rules.*

```
function save_wc_custom_attributes($post_id, $custom_attributes) {
$i = 0;
$product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
$product_id = $post_id;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'pa_farge') ;
// Remove existing colors from the product
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  wp_remove_object_terms( $post_id, $term->term_id, 'pa_farge' );
}
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'pa_str') ;
// Remove existing sizes from the product
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  wp_remove_object_terms( $post_id, $term->term_id, 'pa_str' );
}

foreach ($custom_attributes as $name => $value) {
    // Relate post to a custom attribute, add term if it does not exist
    wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $value, $name, true);
    // Create product attributes array
    $product_attributes[$i] = array(
        'name' => $name, // set attribute name
        'value' => $value, // set attribute value
        'is_visible' => 1,
        'is_variation' => 1,
        'is_taxonomy' => 1
    );
    $i++;
}
// Now update the post with its new attributes
update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes);
// Details for the variation
$variation_post = array(
    'post_title'  => $product->get_name(),
    'post_name'   => 'product-'.$product_id.'-variation',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_parent' => $product_id,
    'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
    'guid'        => $product->get_permalink()
);

if( !$product->has_child() ) { 
  // Creating a single variation if none exists
  $variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation_post );
  $variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
  $variation->set_regular_price( $product->get_price() );
  $variation->save(); // Save the data
  $product_variable = new WC_Product_Variable($post_id);
  $product_variable->sync($post_id);
  wc_delete_product_transients($post_id);
}
else {
  // Update the variation if it already exists
  $product_variable = new WC_Product_Variable($post_id);
  $product_variable->sync($post_id);
  wc_delete_product_transients($post_id);
}
$product->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your actual code is jus setting  product attributes to the main variable product, but it doesn't set any attribute to a product variation… So the question is may be related to this variable product instead…

So try simply to add at the end of your code:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
$product->save();
```

Comment: Uh formatting got bad. But added some code to show that the variable product is created. I can also see it back-end as this:
https://imgur.com/a/0ULPKJa

Comment: @BTB It should be better if you add all related code in your question directly with explanations (and remove it from comments).

Comment: Thanks - updated the question with full code and some comments.